# protobuf python error "cannot assign to extension because it is a repeated or composite type"

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

when build the proto object, "TypeError: Cannot assign to extension "actionRequest" because it is a repeated or composite type."

proto file:

```
message Message{
    message MessageContent{
        extensions 100 to max;
    }
     optional MessageContent content = 1;
}
message ActionRequest{
    optional string token = 1;
```

`}`

```
extend Message.MessageContent {
   optional ActionRequest actionRequest = 200;
}
```

code:

```
import TestPb_pb2
message = TestPb_pb2.Message()
request = TestPb_pb2.ActionRequest()
message.content.Extensions[TestPb_pb2.actionRequest] = request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Protocol Buffers Python API automatically constructs an instance of the extension message for you. So instead of assigning to the `message.content.Extensions[TestPb_pb2.actionRequest]`, you can write to the preconstructed message:

`message.content.Extensions[TestPb_pb2.actionRequest].token = "foobar"`

(As to why the API is designed this way, I do not know.)

Comment: Note that regular (non-extension) fields work similarly.  It was designed this way so that the Python API could wrap the C++ implementation for performance.  Since the C++ API doesn't have GC or reference counting, you cannot link the same message object into two different parents, so the API was designed to prevent you from trying.  (That was the reasoning, anyway -- I'm not necessarily saying this was a good decision.)